# Custom keyboard layout folder not updating in mac Monterey

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Im trying to create a custom keyboard layout using ukelele.
I forgot to add spacebar (lol) to the layout file that i added to `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`.

The issue that im having is that when i save a new copy of the layout file to the folder the "others" section in input sources doesn't update. Instead it seems to just show another copy of the first draft layout file that i saved. Doesn't matter if I save the new file with a new file name, still creates shows a copy of the first file. Already tried rebooting.

source output screenshot
[image]

keyboard Layout folder
[image]

Comment: User layouts don't go in /Library, they go in ~/Library. On anything newer than Catalina, I'm surprised it even let you try to put files in there.